# Compiler Shows: Abort Called

Tags: algorithm, syntax, c++

When does a C++ program throw this error message:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
    what():  basic_string::at: __n (which is 0) >= this->size() (which is 0)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I was trying an algorithm problem on a website.
My function was:

```
int stringSimilarity(string s)
{
    int size=s.size(), sum=0;
    
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        string sub_str; int temp_sum=0;
        //Creating a substring for comparison
        for(int j=i, l=0; j<size, l<size-i; j++, l++)           
        {
            sub_str.at(l)=s.at(j);
        }

        if(sub_str.at(0)==s.at(0))
        {
            temp_sum++;
            int k=1;
            while(sub_str.at(k)==s.at(k))
            {
                temp_sum++;
                k++;
            }
        }
        sum=sum+temp_sum;
    }

    return sum;
}
```

While running sample test cases, I got the error message I showed above. Can someone please tell me where am I going wrong?

**EDIT:**
Made the question to the point. In the original question, I had asked why my program was not compiling. But as many pointed out, it is not a compilation error, but a run-time error thrown by the program.

Comment: We don't deal with actual code on this site. But note that your code does *compile*, i.e., the exception you see is a runtime error. It's caused by off-indexing a container like a string. That is, say a string has three elements but you try to access the fourth element.

Comment: Where can I get proper help? And can you find the point where I am exceeding the limit of the container? And one more thing, what is this site for, then?

Comment: The problem is that `sub_str` is empty, but you try to access `sub_str.at(l)`, where `l` is 0 and this element does not exist. I've flagged your question for migration to [SO], which does deal with actual implementations. However, your question might violate some of their policies but I'm not sure.

Comment: Please include problem statement and error message as text, not images. Also, please describe what you've tried; have you written tests, have you used a debugger, etc.

Comment: @mrm Make an answer?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `j<size && l<size-i;` not `j<size, l<size-i;`  ?
I may be a bit behind in modern coding, as I haven't touched C++ in the last 7 years.

Comment: The compiler didn't do any of this. Your program did it. Please express yourself clearly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation of [std::string::at()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/at/)

> The function automatically checks whether pos is the valid position of
>   a character in the string (i.e., whether pos is less than the string
>   length), throwing an out_of_range exception if it is not.

In here, `sub_str` is an empty string (length 0), but you try to access it in the first line of your inner loop:

```
    sub_str.at(l)=s.at(j);
```

One way to overcome it could be to initialize the string to have the same length of `s`, and edit it in place.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue when I was doing code on HackerRank,So let me tell you what was my mistake:

I was taking one extra input which was not mentioned in test case so when i removed that my problem got solved.

Program was saying user will give two queries and i have to work on those queries but I was taking the query numbers too.

It was like

cin >> query;

And then i was taking 2 query q1 and q1 so during run time compiler said Abort Called and when i remove this(cin >> query;) line,My program worked fine.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The suggested edit indicates that you realised this answer is incorrect. Either edit your answer for it to become correct, or delete it altogether.